# Is it wise to use a PayPal account for donations larger than $1 million/month?

Tags: united-states, paypal, donation

If I am about to receive multiple $5 donations that would sum up to over a million dollars per month, would it be wise to use a PayPal account?

I can't confirm my nonprofit 501(c)(3) status and I don't care to because transaction fees are the same for over $100K/month, but would there be anything I should be cautious of?

Comment: You can't confirm your status as a 501(c)3? But Don't the donors care? Doesn't the IRS care?

Comment: Is handling over a million dollar a month still in scope for *personal* finance?

Comment: May I ask, what the donations will be for? What is your idea / charity / company doing? Just purely curious!

Comment: @Rob Evans,I was going to offer membership (which would lead to certain privileges) in "exchange" of donations, but PayPal is extremely strict in regard to donated money, so it is out of the question, no to mention the tight withdrawal rules.

Comment: @Philipp Does "Personal finance and money" mean "Personal finance and personal money" or "Money in general and personal finance"?

Comment: Just read this http://www.somethingawful.com/news/paypal-fiasco-summary/ horror story how PayPal handles such situations.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Looking at the ["What topics can I ask about here"](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of the help center says that questions about corporate and small business finances are off-topic. When you handle $1 million as a non-profit organization you are in that area.

Comment: @Agent_L That story is from 10 years ago. How much of it does still apply to the *current* business practices of Paypal?

Comment: @Philipp 10 years and PayPal **still** haven't changed a bit of "we own your soul" attitude in their T&C.

Comment: @Agent_L The article states that Paypal can do whatever they want because they are not a bank. Two years later, [they officially became one](https://en.wikinews.org/wiki/PayPal_receives_banking_licence).

Comment: @Philipp you must still be careful with PayPal, my company uses them and PayPal can freeze your withdraws whenever/why-ever they feel like it.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't trust PayPal to hold $1 let alone $1M

Comment: @Philipp PayPal is not a bank in the US.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is not wise.

I think that if your charity gets $1M/month (or even $100K/month) in donations, it would be prudent to have a (good) accountant oversee your operations, and use a proper FDIC-insured banking system.

I'm aware of a company who was using PayPal for retail sales and got stuck with hundreds of thousands of dollars on their PayPal account and could only withdraw hundreds (500, in fact) every day. It took some time for them to recover the money, and with some pressure too. Admittedly, the company used PayPal incorrectly, but have you read their terms and conditions? Not sure if using them "correctly" is even possible.

You can use e-check, merchant accounts (Square for example will ACH-deposit to your bank) for credit cards, etc.

Comment: +1 for `Not sure if using them "correctly" is even possible.`

Comment: I see. Upon further research it seems you're only allowed to withdraw 500 Euro / day and that's certainly not what I want. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: @IneedHelp right, it was 500/day, not 500/month. Still, they couldn't withdraw the money for many many years at that pace, they had to use their lawyers to resolve this with PayPal. Not a situation you want to find yourself in.

Comment: Paypal's EULA is to finance the labor equivalent of a XIX century coal mine work contract. You have almost no guarantees, and since it is not a bank, it is not subject to bank regulations.

Comment: Beware that Paypal can change terms on you as well whenever they want.  I got burned by that back in the early days.  As a result Paypal is now firmly on my list of companies I try not to deal with at all.

Comment: On the topic of Square vs traditional merchant accounts, here's an interesting post on warning signs to watch out for in banks' merchant agreements (and reasons why Square may have the advantage): http://davidmalki.tumblr.com/post/120645714068/this-has-bugged-me-for-a-long-time-ive-received